# Docusign attachment file size limitation

Tags: attachment, docusignapi

Is there a way to limit the signer attachment file size in docusign, either using the API or through settings at the DocuSign web site.  I have read (in the [API guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/GettingStarted/File%20Size%20Limitations.htm)) that there is a 25 MB limit for attachments.  Is there any way to restrict this to a smaller number?

Curiously, the document that triggered this issue was 31 MB in size.  Our customer was able to upload a document that big, but our application experienced timeout issues because it took too long to download it.  Why was the customer able to upload such a big attachment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**[1]**  No there is not currently a way that outside applications could limit the platform wide limit of ~25MB per envelope that DocuSign has in place.  It is recommended that you add logic to your app/integration that checks the file size BEFORE you make the API call to create the envelope and stops the user from using that document if it's too large.

**[2]**  The reason why a particular 30MB document was accepted by the platform but other 30MB documents might error out is due to encryption.  Whenever you create a new DocuSign envelope the system automatically encrypts and hashes each document.  This in turn bloats the envelope larger.  The true limit of the platform is actually 50MB per envelope, so based on the actual data and bytes of your docs different ones will be enlarged to different sizes, and some will exceed that 50MB limit whereas others might not.